# CakePHP recursive 2 with translate behavior

Tags: cakephp, recursion, internationalization, cakephp-2.3

I would like find all relations by code:

```
$this->set('types', $this->Project->ProjectType->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2)));
```

I get error when I set recursive to 2:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'I18n__name.content' in 'field list'
```

Model `ProjectType` using Translate Behavior for `content` field (text type).
Other recursive works good.
How return results for `recursive = 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use recursive at all.

Set it to `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel, and don't change it after that.  Then use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) to retrieve associated data.

Recursive will give you more headaches than it's worth.  If Containable wasn't so easy/awesome, maybe we'd be stuck using recursive, but... it IS awesome and it IS easy :)

Comment: Okey, I check later this behavior, but where is problem in my question? Because I use Translate Behavior?